# python typecheck module in "mastering Matplotlib" book

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I reading the book "Mastering Matplotlib" By Duncan M. McGreggor
in many of the juniper notebook examples there is a reference to a "typecheck" module.
I get the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typecheck'

for example in:
https://github.com/masteringmatplotlib/interaction/blob/master/notebooks/mmpl-interaction.ipynb

there is:
from typecheck import typecheck

I have been searching the web, where is this module?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install it first. In one cell of the jupyter notebook, type:

```
!pip install typecheck
```

Then you can use it normally.

Note: this module is only supported for python 2+. You cannot use it in python3.

Note2: The module can be found here: https://pypi.org/project/typecheck/

Edit:

For the book, it seems that you can check his requirements.txt file, he lists the following packages:

```
setuptools
flake8
typecheck-decorator == 0.3b
```

So it seems that you will need to install `typecheck-decorator` which supports python 3. It can be found here: https://github.com/prechelt/typecheck-decorator

Comment: thank you Mohammad but it does not seem right, the book is using python 3.4

Comment: @MaxBonino See my edit, it seems that the author is using a different module that supports python3. Good luck!